# Build <ul> list recursively

Tags: java, jsp, recursion

So, I have this site structure

```
Page 1
  Page 1.1
Page 2
  Page 2.1
    Page 2.1.1
  Page 2.2
Page 3
  Page 3.1
  Page 3.2
Page 4
```

and I want to build `<ul>` list using recursive function. My function looks like this

```
public String getMenu(Page rootPage, boolean base){
    final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    Iterator<Page> subPages = rootPage.listChildren();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("<ul");
        output.append(" id=\"drop-menu\"");
    output.append(" class=\"popup-menu\">");
    if(!base){
        output.append("<li><a href=\"").append(rootPage.getPath()).append(".html\" class=\"showSubPage\" rel=\"").append(rootPage.getPath()).append("\">");
        String title = rootPage.getPageTitle() == null ? rootPage.getTitle() : rootPage.getPageTitle();
        output.append(title);
        output.append("</a>");
        output.append("</li>");
        output.append("</ul>");
    }
    while(subPages.hasNext()){
        output.append("<ul>");
        log.info("som subpages here!");
        Page curPage = subPages.next();
        output.append("<li><a href=\"").append(curPage.getPath()).append(".html\" class=\"showSubPage\" rel=\"").append(curPage.getPath()).append("\">");
        String title = curPage.getPageTitle() == null ? curPage.getTitle() : curPage.getPageTitle();
        output.append(title);
        output.append("</a>");
        Iterator<Page> subSub = curPage.listChildren();
        int tmpCtr = 0;
        while(subSub.hasNext()){
            tmpCtr++;
            output.append(getMenu(subSub.next(), false));
        }
        output.append("</li>");
        output.append("</ul>");
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

and the output looks like this

```
<ul id="drop-menu" class="popup-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/menu-hier/afsafa.html" class="showSubPage" >Page 1</a>
            <ul id="drop-menu" class="popup-menu">
                <li><a href="/menu-hier/afsafa/sdgsdgdsf.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/afsafa/sdgsdgdsf">Page 1.1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/menu-hier/fdsafdsafas.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/fdsafdsafas">Page 2</a>
            <ul id="drop-menu" class="popup-menu">
                <li><a href="/menu-hier/fdsafdsafas/sdfgdsgsdg.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/fdsafdsafas/sdfgdsgsdg">Page 2.1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/menu-hier/fdsafdsafas/sdfgdsgsdg/dsgsdgdsgfd.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/fdsafdsafas/sdfgdsgsdg/dsgsdgdsgfd">Page 2.1.1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="drop-menu" class="popup-menu">
                <li><a href="/menu-hier/fdsafdsafas/fsdgdsfgsdgfs.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/fdsafdsafas/fsdgdsfgsdgfs">Page 2.2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/menu-hier/fgdsgfsdgdsfgsdg.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/fgdsgfsdgdsfgsdg">Page 3</a>
            <ul id="drop-menu" class="popup-menu">
                <li><a href="/menu-hier/fgdsgfsdgdsfgsdg/fsafsdafas.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/fgdsgfsdgdsfgsdg/fsafsdafas">Page 3.1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="drop-menu" class="popup-menu">
                <li><a href="/menu-hier/fgdsgfsdgdsfgsdg/yxvcxyvvyxcv.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/fgdsgfsdgdsfgsdg/yxvcxyvvyxcv">Page 3.2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="drop-menu" class="popup-menu">
                <li><a href="/menu-hier/fgdsgfsdgdsfgsdg/yxvcxyv.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/fgdsgfsdgdsfgsdg/yxvcxyv">Page 3.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/menu-hier/dsfgsdfgdsfg.html" class="showSubPage" rel="/menu-hier/dsfgsdfgdsfg">Page 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

So the problem is, that the level 3 pages aren't placed properly. For example the Page 2.1.1 isn't under the Page 2.1 section.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and stepping through each line to understand how it is behaving. You will learn a lot that way.

Comment: @SimonArsenault thank you for answer but unfortunattely I can't debug and step through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, how you want your HTML to look like, but:

1) From your code, the `<ul>` tag is inserted twice for sub-pages (once in the while loop, then in the recursive called getMenu() again)

2) I think, you are missing the `<li>` tags below the `<ul>` tags.

3) Your code looks quite redundant and complex, can't it be done easier like so (not tested):

```
public String getMenu(Page page, boolean isRoot) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if (isRoot) {
        output.append("<ul id=\"drop-menu\"");
        output.append(" class=\"popup-menu\">");
        }
    else {
        output.append("<ul>");
        }
    output.append("<li><a href=\"")
        .append(page.getPath())
        .append(".html\" class=\"showSubPage\" rel=\"")
        .append(rootPage.getPath()).append("\">");
    String title = page.getPageTitle() == null ? page.getTitle() : page.getPageTitle();
    output.append(title);
    output.append("</a>");

    Iterator<Page> subPages = page.listChildren();
    while(subPages.hasNext()){
        output.append(getMenu(subPages.next(), false));
    }
    output.append("</li>");
    output.append("</ul>");
    return output.toString();
}
```